# Removing empty space between table rows/columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So there's this white space that I need to remove and I am at a loss for how to achieve this.

Here's the HTML representation of the actual React code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=   , initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <div class="tableTitle"></div>
        <table class="subtable">
            <tr class="monthDisplay"></tr>
            <tr class="tableRow1">
                <tr></tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>The problematic row after which the line appears</tr>
                <td class="problematicColumn"> //It seems that these columns also add some height
                    <tr>Jan 9, 2024</tr>
                    <tr>$214.41</tr>
                    <tr>$214.01</tr>
                    <tr>$6.61</tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                </td>
                ... 
            </tr>
            <tr class="tableRow2">
                <tr></tr>
                <tr></tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr class="tableRow3">
                <tr></tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the actual image (removed specific data) to highlight the issue. The red arrow points at the space that I need to remove.

[image]

Me highlighting the `problematicColumn` in HTML inspector

[image]

Any ideas on how to do a clean removal of the blank space?

Comment: If this code is a direct copy, then it seems your HTML is incorrect. You have nested `<tr>` tags inside `<td>` tags which you cannot do. As well as having multiple nested rows when it seems like you meant to use columns instead. Otherwise, it is likely a problem with padding or margin properties not being set to `0`.

Comment: Indeed there are nested `<tr>` tags inside `<td>`, that's how the app was built. I'm new here so I didn't really write this code.

Answer (score 0):

this have to fix it:

```
<td class="problematicColumn" style={{padding:'0px', margin:'0px'}}>
```

or maybe the problem is on the row, then:

```
<tr class="tableRow1" style={{padding:'0px', margin:'0px'}} >
```

play with that and u will fix it

Comment: Adding `{{padding:'0px', margin:'0px'}}` to the `td` element reduces the blank space to bare minimum, but it pushes that row really close to the one above it.